# Can I leverage ASP.NET Core MVC framework to validate view model so validation summary is shown on viewing of form initially as well as submission?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Given an ASP.NET Core MVC controller method with no parameters.

Given a view model is created and partially populated with third-party data within the controller method.

Given my C# models have properly defined data annotations for property validation.

Is it possible to leverage the ASP.NET Core MVC framework to validate my view model such that `Html.ValidationSummary()` shows errors from the pre-populated view model on initial viewing of the form (as opposed to only showing on the submission of the form)?

Controller:

```
public IActionResult ViewForm() 
{
     MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel();

     // Pre-populate view model with some data (which may be invalid).
     viewModel.MyRequiredProperty = someThirdPartyDataSource.Value;

     //I want to validate here so pre-populated data errors are shown
     //in the views "Html.ValidationSummary()".

     return View(viewModel);
}
```

Models:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
     public MyObjectToValidate MyObject { get; set; }
}

public class MyObjectToValidate
{
     [Key]
     public int ID { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage="Property is required.")]
     public string MyRequiredProperty
}
```

Maybe I can... (couldn't find solid answers to these looking through documentation myself)

1. Manually bind and validate the viewModel somehow prior to calling `return View(viewModel)`?
2. Take advantage of `ViewResult myViewResult = View(viewModel);`?

Comment: Could you please share your full code along with what you are trying to acheive , your question is not clear, if you are wanted to know whether you can set validation on your `viewModel` the answer is yes you can, so for your context share us the scenario so that we can reproduce your problem then can help you.

Comment: The simple controller example demonstrates exactly what I want to achieve. I want the view model validated prior to passing the model to the view the first time. This way a validation summary will show on the users first viewing of a form on the view.

Comment: Yes you can bind the `ViewModel` from your Id or parameter from user request and finally return that viewModel. If you have any implementational challenge you could share with us.

Comment: I see where the confusion may be now. This controller method is only to view the form not submit it. The ID here is only to select data from the third party that populates this view model. If I'm understanding correctly, you're saying I could add an additional parameter and have a blank view model passed in populate/validate and then pass it back to the view. Is there another way where I do not have to have it bound to a parameter coming in? Can I do this from inside the controller after instantiating the view model? Only because ideally I'd like to preserve that signature if possible.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Full controller method pasted [here](https://pastebin.com/yUmHNPHX) (I welcome any critique). I added a comment exactly where I would like to bind/validate the model if possible. If not I guess my only option would be to go back and have the view model passed in as a parameter so it's already bound (and can therefore be validated) coming into the controller as you previously suggested.

Comment: What do you want to do within the controller?  Binding the view as per your requirement?  Yes you can bind new and custom view as you want and then finally return it.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Pretend my controller has no parameters and nothing is bound from the view coming into this controller method (no parameters nothing). Within the controller; I want to create a view model, populate it with data (which may contain errors), validate it, and pass it to a view. I want the form on my view to already be showing a `Html.Validationsummary()` for those errors from the imported data IMMEDIATELY/INITIALLY upon VIEWING the form. My current experience is that the validation summary will not show unless the form is submitted.

Comment: @JohnH this is very helpful to know and likely could've been a solution for my issue but Ian's answer below hit the nail directly on the head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ControllerBase` (which all controllers implicitly inherit from) has a [`TryValidateModel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.tryvalidatemodel#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_TryValidateModel_System_Object_) method that should do exactly what you need. So:

```
public IActionResult ViewForm() 
{
     MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel();

     // Pre-populate view model with some data (which may be invalid).
     viewModel.MyRequiredProperty = someThirdPartyDataSource.Value;

     //I want to validate here so pre-populated data errors are shown
     //in the views "Html.ValidationSummary()".
     TryValidateModel(viewModel);

     return View(viewModel);
}
```